# When crawling, I cannot go to a specific page

Tags: web-crawler

I want to crawl the Korean cryptocurrency community site, Coinpan.

But there is a problem about going to a specific page by inputting the URL on a web browser like Safari or Chrome.

For example, 
If you enter "https://coinpan.com/index.php?mid=free&page=20" on your browser, you should go to the '20' page on the site. But it does not.

When you designate the page number in the URL, you always go to the first page.

What's the problem?

I mainly use R, not Python.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that website supports the `page` query parameter?  It sounds like it doesn't.

Comment: How can I check whether the site supports query parameter? And, how can I crawl the site when it does not?